# Get values from a char array

Tags: c, char

```
FILE *t;
t = fopen(argv[8], "r");
fgets(tmp, 2048, t);
```

What I am reading at each line is something like this "l 23 23" a letter and some numbers (int or float) depending on weather "l" is "a" "b" or "c".

I've tried but couldn't compare tmp[0] with a letter.

```
tmp[0] =="t"
```

I know for sure "t" is present in the file but it always gives `false`.

How do I compare it and also extract the numbers that follow?

PS: I know how many number and what type to expect at each line depending on the value of `tmp[0]`.

Comment: If you want to compare one character, use `'t'`, not `"t"` (single-quotes, not double).

Comment: **TURN ON YOUR COMPILER WARNINGS.** No excuse. Turn the damn warnings on and pay attention to them. (And next time read that beginner's tutorial **attentively.**)

Comment: I'm using gcc in a terminal kind of hard to read them, I'm acutally not new at this but forgot the difference between " and '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the first character in `tmp` with the character `'x'`, then use:

```
if (tmp[0] == 'x')
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to compare the entire string in `tmp` with the string `"xyz"`, then use:

```
if (strcmp(tmp,"xyz") == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

---

**Behind the scene:**

- When you use a double-quoted string of characters in your code, the compiler replaces it with a pointer to the beginning of the memory space in which the string will reside during runtime.
- So by `tmp[0] == "t"`, you are actually attempting to compare a single character (typically 8 bits of data) with a memory address (typically 32 or 64 bits of data, depending on your system).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare one character like that, use `'t'`, not `"t"` (single-quotes, not double).